# gRPC Server Deployed in Container Cannot Establish SSL Connection

Tags: .net-core, https, grpc, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to deploy a simple grpc server written in asp.net core. The Kestrel settings are

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(c =>
                {
                    c.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 8001);
                    c.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(https =>
                    {
                        https.ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2("MyDemo.gRPC.pfx", "Pa55word");
                    });
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

I have created a docker image and deployed it to an Azure Container Instance, and exposed port 8001. When I use an insecure channel to call the server from a client, I get a successful response, i.e

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://01.02.3.04:8001");
```

gets the server to respond. However, when I try to use a secure channel and use https, I get the exception

> Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.

I presume that it is something to do with my Kestrel settings, can anyone see my problem?